# Is there any meaning to Dalton's license plate (DLB 573) in Road House?

Tags: roadhouse

In [Road House](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098206/) the license plate NY DLB 573 of Dalton's car is shown many times

Does the registration number mean anything or was it simply a by product of trying to frame the iconic Mercedes logo?